Different behavior of TIdTCPClient/TIdTCPServer application in Debug/Release complication mode
A very simple Delphi 12 TIdTCPClient/TIdTCPServer application for Windows, under OpenVPN, WORKS fine when the Server app is built and run in Debug mode, and is NOT working when the Server app is built and run in Release mode (a "Connection Times out" error message is raised).
The Server listens on an open port, and the Client sends a string message to the Server VPN socket (public VPN IP and listening port).
Here is a portion of code from the Server and Client sides:
SERVER SIDE
procedure TFormServer.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
Begin
  var StrMsgCli     := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  MemoMsgClient.Text:= StrMsgCli;
End;

CLIENT SIDE
procedure TFormClient.SpeedButtonSendToServerClick(Sender: TObject);
Begin
  var StringToSend:= 'BlaBlaBla_123';
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn(StringToSend);
End;

Can someone solve this issue?

Have you checked your FireWall and Anti-Virus software. It is possible that your release build application is being locked by either of them. In fact once in the past I encountered a problem where my AV has flagged release version of one of my application as potential harmful (based on heuristics) but it was not flagging debug release of the same application as such . I'm guessing that included debug might have affected overall heuristics of the application enough to not get flagged the same way.

TIdTCPServer is a multi-threaded component. Most of its events (including OnExecute) are called in worker threads, not in the main UI thread. So, accessing UI controls directly, like you are with MemoMsgClient, is NOT thread-safe and MUST be synchronized with the main UI thread, such as with TThread.Synchronize() or TThread.Queue(), eg:
procedure TFormServer.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
Begin
  var StrMsgCli := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      MemoMsgClient.Text := StrMsgCli;
    end
  );
End;


Thanks a lot. But the problem, despite the code correction suggested in your answer, is still here... Message exchange over OVPN works only with the server app compiled in Debug mode. I wonder what the difference could be between "debug EXE" (run outside the IDE, with a simple double click) and "release EXE" in the TCP communication protocol.

There is no difference between release mode and debug mode as far as TCP is concerned. So something else is going on. You are going to have to debug your code deeper. What you have shown should work just fine on all platforms. As for the UI issue, it might not be THE problem but it is A problem that you need to fix so it is not a contributing factor.

Thanks.
The above code works in both modes if the server and client apps are in a LAN with open "speaking" port.
It is only on OVPN (Open VPN) that a different behavior occurs.
